# MSBuild incremental build error

Tags: msbuild, incremental-build

I am facing one problem in building and copying .NET solution output to a deployment folder.

What i want to do is. Build solution and put the output into C:\TempOutput

then copy the outfiles from C:\TempOutput to another deployment folder.

at 1st attemp it creates folder in C:\TempOutput and creates output dlls and exes in this folder

also it creates folder "Exec\Debug\Bin" but does not copy files from C:\TempOutput

logs says that

> Target CopyBuildFiles:
>         Skipping target "CopyBuildFiles" because it has no outputs.

When i run the script again this time it copies the files from C:\TempOutput to "Exec\Debug\Bin"

Am i missing something? Why it is not detecting output at 1st attempt?

following is the msbuild script

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Deploy">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectName>Common Projects</ProjectName>
    <SolutionFilePath>..\..\Solution\Solution.sln</SolutionFilePath>

    <!--Build/Rebuild-->
    <BuildType>Build</BuildType>

    <!--Debug -> output : local-->
    <!--Release -> output : local-->
    <!--ProduDbg -> output : X:\Debug-->
    <!--ProduRel -> output : X:\Release-->

    <BuildMode>Debug</BuildMode>

    <OutputPath>..\Exec\$(BuildMode)\Bin\</OutputPath>
    <ExecPath>..\..\bin\$(BuildMode)</ExecPath>

    <DestinitionFolder>$(OutputPath)</DestinitionFolder>
    <SubDirPath>$(ExecPath)\**</SubDirPath>

    <BuildFolder>C:\TempOutputs\</BuildFolder>  

  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <File Include="
          $(BuildFolder)\*.*
          "

          Exclude="          
          $(BuildFolder)\*.vshost*
          "
          >

    </File> 

  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="PreBuild">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(BuildFolder)" />
    <MakeDir Directories="$(DestinitionFolder)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Compile">

    <MakeDir Directories="$(BuildFolder)" />
    <!-- Build does build only-->

    <Message Text="*******************************************************"/>
    <Message Text="-->Building $(ProjectName)"/>
    <Message Text="*******************************************************"/>

    <Message Text="*******************************************************"/>
    <Message Text="-->Building in [$(BuildMode) | $(BuildType)] mode"/>
    <Message Text="*******************************************************"/>

    <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionFilePath)" Targets="$(BuildType)" Properties="Configuration=$(BuildMode);OutDir=$(BuildFolder)"/>    
  </Target>


  <Target Name="CopyBuildFiles"
             Inputs="@(File)"
             Outputs=
          "@(File->'$(DestinitionFolder)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')">

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(File)"
          DestinationFiles="@(File->'$(DestinitionFolder)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
          />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Deploy">

    <CallTarget Targets="PreBuild"/>
    <CallTarget Targets="Compile"/>

    <Message Text="*******************************************************"/>
    <Message Text="@(File)"/>
    <Message Text="$(DestinitionFolder)"/>    
    <Message Text="*******************************************************"/>


    <CallTarget Targets="CopyBuildFiles"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this bit

```
  <Target Name="CopyBuildFiles"              
          Inputs="@(File)"
          Outputs="@(File->'$(DestinitionFolder)%(File.RecursiveDir)%(File.Filename)%(File.Extension)')">

      <Copy SourceFiles="@(File)"
            DestinationFiles="@(File->'$(DestinitionFolder)%(File.RecursiveDir)%(File.Filename)%(File.Extension)')"/>
   </Target>
```